# Designing a hash function to generate the same hash from different passwords

Tags: algorithm, hash

Problem goes as this:
Assume that your algorithm divide the given string into three character blocks and XOR them. Then it takes the result pass it through existing MD5 hash algorithm. This algorithm, for instance, would give same hash values for "FOO" and "FOOFOOFOO".

In his example, I am having trouble understanding how XORing the blocks creates the same hash values. Can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: Why can't you just ignore the prefix magic character sequence and take hash of the remaining?

Comment: He wants it to be done with simple bitwise operations.

Comment: BTW: You should remove the cryptography tag and add a homework tag.

Comment: @krynr: the homework tag has been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @DMS: Thanks for pointing out. I still think the cryptography tag is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you XOR a value with itself you get 0 and if you XOR 0 with something you get the same something back. We get `"FOO" XOR "FOO" = "\0\0\0"` and `"\0\0\0" XOR "FOO" = "FOO"`. I leave the rest up to you. :-)

Comment: I guess you could have it [x1 xor x2 xor x3] and given that the magic sequence can be split into two parts, x1 and x2 and the xor of this equals 0 will make it work. But this means the sequence would have to repeat itself, for example abcabc. I am trying to think of something where the magic sequence isn't repeating but having a hard time doing so.

Comment: Split the sequence into blocks with the same length as the magic string. XOR every block with the magic sequence. XOR all blocks together piece by piece.